# How to make a section with absolute positioning responsive in CSS

Tags: html, css

I used a layout with absolute positioning, and now I am wondering if there is anyway to make it responsive when the screen gets smaller, or if I should just stay away from absolute positioning.

When the screen gets smaller the images in absolute position are on top of the other content. I know this is because they are removed from the flow of the page when in absolute position. However, I do not understand why they are creating a huge space in the MIDDLE?? So they stay in position horizontally, but vertically a HUGE space appears between the images in row 1 and row 2. I do not know how to make them stay in their own 'section' which is the class .books in the code when I have already tried changing the height of the section.

```css
.image {
  width:20%;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;  
}

.books{
  width: 100%;
  height:1000px;
  /*max-width:100%;*/
  padding:0;
  margin:2px; 
  /*position:absolute;*/
}

.interpreter{
  position:absolute;
  left:28%;
  top:20%;
  box-shadow: 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.namesake{
  position:absolute;
  left:49%;
  top:20%;
  box-shadow: 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.lowland{
  position:absolute;
  left:28%;
  top:82%;
  box-shadow: 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.unaccustomed{
  position:absolute;
  right:31%;
  top:82%;
  box-shadow: 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  z-index:2;
}

.interpreter-caption{
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;
  left:5%;
}

.namesake-caption{
  position:absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right:7%;
}

.unaccustomed-caption{
  position:absolute;
  top:82%;
  right:7%;
}

.lowland-caption{
  position:absolute;
  left:5%;
  top:82%;
}
```

```html
<div class="books">
    <div class=img-div>
    <img class="image interpreter" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41ffYO-4WQL.jpg">
    <figcaption class="img-caption interpreter-caption"><h3>Interpreter of Maladies</h3><blockquote cite="https://www.randomhouse.com/kvpa/jhumpalahiri/books.php"><p>INTERPRETER OF MALADIES navigates between inherited Indian traditions and a baffling new world. The characters in Jhumpa Lahiri's elegant, touching stories seek love beyond the barriers of culture and generations. In "A Temporary Matter," published in The New Yorker, a young Indian-American couple faces the heartbreak of a stillborn birth while their Boston neighborhood copes with a nightly blackout. In the title story, an interpreter guides an American family through the India of their ancestors and hears an astonishing confession. Lahiri writes with deft cultural insight.</p></blockquote><p></figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="img-div">
    <img class="image namesake" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Q2RYbNslL.jpg">
    <figcaption class="img-caption namesake-caption"><h3>The Namesake</h3><blockquote cite="https://www.randomhouse.com/kvpa/jhumpalahiri/books.php"><p>THE NAMESAKE follows the Ganguli family through its journey from Calcutta to Cambridge to the Boston suburbs. Ashima and Ashoke Ganguli arrive in America at the end of the 1960s, shortly after their arranged marriage in Calcutta, in order for Ashoke to finish his engineering degree at MIT. Ashoke is forward-thinking, ready to enter into American culture if not fully at least with an open mind. His young bride is far less malleable. Isolated, desperately missing her large family back in India, she will never be at peace with this new world.</p></blockquote></figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="img-div">
    <img class="image unaccustomed" src="https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1320398140l/85301.jpg">
    <figcaption class="img-caption unaccustomed-caption"><h3>Unaccustomed Earth</h3><blockquote cite="https://www.randomhouse.com/kvpa/jhumpalahiri/books.php"><p>UNACCUSTOMED EARTH is a superbly crafted new work of fiction: eight stories—longer and more emotionally complex than any she has yet written. Stories that take us from Cambridge and Seattle to India and Thailand as they enter the lives of sisters and brothers, fathers and mothers, daughters and sons, friends and lovers.</p></blockquote></figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="img-div">
    <img class="image lowland" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/02/The_Lowland_%28novel%29.jpg/220px-The_Lowland_%28novel%29.jpg">
    <figcaption class="img-caption lowland-caption"><h3>The Lowland</h3><blockquote cite="https://www.randomhouse.com/kvpa/jhumpalahiri/books.php"><p>THE LOWLAND, about brothers born just fifteen months apart. Subhash and Udayan Mitra are inseparable, one often mistaken for the other in the Calcutta neighborhood where they grow up. But they are also opposites, with gravely different futures ahead. It is the 1960s, and Udayan—charismatic and impulsive—finds himself drawn to the Naxalite movement, a rebellion waged to eradicate inequity and poverty; he will give everything, risk all, for what he believes. Subhash, the dutiful son, does not share his brother’s political passion; he leaves home to pursue a life of scientific research in a quiet, coastal corner of America.</p></blockquote></figcaption>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. the image has top: 20% || so it will be 20% away from the top from
   its relative parent.
2. the images have width: 20% || you dont have
   any defined height, and the images in html/css scale down and up
   respecting their aspect ratio. which means the image will be smaller
   in width AND height.
3. since the image go smaller when the parent
   is smaller (the 20% width are equals to 20% of parents width), and
   images respect aspect ratio, u end up in space in the middle.

Advices:
1- if you have some nasty markup u want to build, and you dont see any other solution than absolute, consider wrapping all the divs in 1 absolute container, and position that container where you want. Inside that container you have a normal elements flow, so you can easilly do flex, grid, and so on there.

here is a fast example of a centered absolute wrapper.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 22vw;
     object-fit: cover;
}
img.full {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrapper .img-box {
          flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-section">
  <p>whatever text you have</p>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-box"><img class="full" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2920849/pexels-photo-2920849.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="img-box"><img class="full" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5091791/pexels-photo-5091791.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="img-box"><img class="full" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4903255/pexels-photo-4903255.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260" alt=""/></div>
    <div class="img-box"><img class="full" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3659132/pexels-photo-3659132.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260" alt=""/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you study to learn this? If you don't mind my asking. Clearly, it works, I just am not familiar with a lot of the code you used. I'm taking a CSS course, but never come across -o-object-fit and -webkit-box,  etc.

Comment: It took me 2 full hard working years to finally be called a css guru in the company :) i checked million codepens to see how the are build, then introduced my own solutions, then i was starting to understand css hacks. I as well took a scss course on Udemy by Jonathan. Oh dont mind the prefixes like -o- they are auto generated, i wrote the original css in scss.

Comment: I really want to figure this out! If you are willing, would you be able to explain why you set a height, then on those same images width is 100%. Does this mean it is 100% of its container? But you have 4 images so how does that work?

Comment: Then, for its wrapper you are not allowing it to grow or shrink, but what does flex basis at 50% do?

Comment: Hey, each image in its own box, and each box has flex; 0 0 50% which means the ideal size is 50%. Now the image has width: 100% which means it will fully fill its parent which has flex 50%,  so u end up with 2 images each taking 50% of .wrapper width and with flex wrap: wrap, other img-box wrap into the 2nd row and so on.

Comment: I understand! Yay! I hope you don’t mind my asking again, but you have been a really helpful resource. You mentioned that you are working with css at your company. Does this mean you are primarily working on the front end building websites? I am asking because I am curious if there are other uses for css outside of building websites. 
Or, if you are using other programming languages, what is the best one to learn if you want to be able to build more than websites and you enjoy the kind of abstract shape shifting that css offers. Any thoughts? Lol.

Comment: Hey, i am FE developer mainly with some BE experience. So yeah mainly scss for websites, and as well for Electrol desktop apps and Mobile apps with React native or any other similar Framework. Main lang of course JS/TS.